# Formatting String output

Tags: java, string, format, printf, string-formatting

I am trying to format strings so that it prints out with a width of three always and ending at the same line despite how large the number is. Every number but one is a decimal below ten; however, when I print the one above ten that is a decimal the width is four and ends past the last digit of the previous numbers. I would like to make it so that they all end at the same spot and line up on the right by that. How can I do this using printf in Java?

```
[a 4.34]
[b 0.32]
[c 12.52]
```

I would like each of those to line up like so

```
[a 4.34]
[b 0.32]
[c 12.5]
```

Here is what I already have for the line that prints

```
for(int i = 0; i < 26;i++)
{
    System.out.printf("[%c %3.2f]\n", letters[i], frequencies[i]);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the resulting width vary based on the widest row, go with the answer user1544460 gave, or just define multiple print statements with the same if-then-else structure.  If you always want the width to be the same (max for all), you need to specify more digits in your formatted string.

"%3.2f" means "I want a number that has at LEAST 3 spaces TOTAL, TWO of which I want to go toward its value after the decimal point."

Change

```
System.out.printf("[%c %3.2f]\n", letters[i], frequencies[i]);
```

to

```
System.out.printf("[%c %5.2f]\n", letters[i], frequencies[i]);
```

Assuming the maximum value has 3 digits left of the decimal point.

If you want it to work dynamically, and resize to fit the largest row, do this:

```
if(maxNum >= 100)
    System.out.printf("[%c %5.2f]\n", letters[i], frequencies[i]);
else if(maxNum >= 10)
    System.out.printf("[%c %4.2f]\n", letters[i], frequencies[i]);
else // If we get here, we've either coded something wrong, or it's less than 10.
    System.out.printf("[%c %3.2f]\n", letters[i], frequencies[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
System.out.printf("[%c %3.2f]\n", letters[i], frequencies[i]);
```

with

```
System.out.printf("[%c %3.3g]\n", letters[i], frequencies[i]);
```

`"g"` means [significant figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) rather than places after the decimal point, so 3 is used.

For more information, see the [Javadoc for the formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming numbers are always less than 100

```
private static DecimalFormat df1digit = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
private static DecimalFormat df2digit = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
private static DecimalFormat df3digit = new DecimalFormat("##.0");
```

You can compare you number with 10 and 1 use the relevant decimal format. You can extend this idea to format millions, billions etc.

```
if(x>10){
    System.out.println(df3digit.format(x));
}else if(x>1){
    System.out.println(df2digit.format(x));
}else{
    System.out.println(df1digit.format(x));
}
```

0 in format string will handle pure integers if there are any so that you will always get same length of numbers.